# How to make algebraic dependence explicit

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Here is a possibly standard question, from someone who is in no way an expert. The scenario is taken from Shafarevich, Basic Algebraic Geometry 1, ch. 1, §6.3, proof of Thm. 1.25(ii).

Let us have a regular map $f:V\rightarrow W$ ($V,W$ open in $\mathbb{A}^{N},\mathbb{A}^{M}$ respectively, and $f(V)$ dense in $W$); passing to the pullback $f^{*}$, this translates to an inclusion of the function field $k(W)$ into $k(V)$. We write $k[v_{1},\ldots,v_{N}]$ for $k[V]$, and $k[w_{1},\ldots,w_{M}]$ for $k[W]$ (the $v_{i}$ and $w_{j}$ are like the coordinates of $\mathbb{A}^{N},\mathbb{A}^{M}$ modulo the relations given by the definition of $V,W$, if my imagination serves me right). If $\dim(V)=n>m=\dim(W)$, then $k(V)$ has transcendence degree $n-m$ over $k(W)$, which means that wlog we have $v_{1},\ldots,v_{n-m}$ algebraically independent over $k(W)$ and that in principle we also have $F_{i}(v_{i};v_{1},\ldots,v_{n-m};w_{1},\ldots,w_{M})=0$ for some $F_{i}$ for all $n-m< i\leq N$: here each $F_{i}$ is a polynomial in one variable (i.e. the $v_{i}$) over $k(W)[v_{1},\ldots,v_{n-m}]$.

My question is: how can one explicitly obtain the $F_{i}$ (from $f$ and the polynomials defining $V,W$)? Or at least, can we find bounds for their degrees, including the degrees of their coefficients as functions of the $w_{j}$? If standard, references are welcome!

Comment: I think you can compute $F_i$ using elimination theory and grobner bases, e.g., with the software Macaulay2.

Comment: @wnx Thanks, that's exactly the input I needed! Just to answer my own question: one can look at the undergraduate book by Cox, Little and O'Shea (§3.1) and use the elimination theorem with the ordering $w_{1}\prec\ldots\prec w_{M}\prec v_{1}\prec\ldots\prec v_{n-m}\prec v_{i}\prec v_{n-m+1}\prec\ldots\prec v_{N}$ (add one $z$ to homogenize and multiply away the denominators, if necessary) to get inside a Gröbner basis an $F_{i}$ as the one we already know exists by algebraic dependence. Then Dubé (1990) gives degree bounds for reduced Gröbner basis elements wrt $N,M,\deg(V),\deg(W),\deg(f)$.